# sendSignedTransaction web3js

Tags: web3js, gas, raw-transaction, fees

I see that with `sendTransaction` you can specify `maxFeePerGas`.

[see here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html?highlight=sendTransaction#sendtransaction)

However, if you use `signTransaction` and then `sendSignedTransaction` you can only send `gas`. [and here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts-signtransaction).

How to send a signed transaction and specifying gas? (with max priority fee, akin to metamask) ?

Comment: Isn't that what `gasPrice` is supposed to do ?

Comment: Is it? couldn't find enough information on doc, could you link it ?

Comment: Never mind, the londond fork seems to have modified the logic behind gas price and I was not aware of that: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#pre-london

Comment: Any idea how we can go about it then?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not up-to-date, you can use `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas` without problem.

`gas` is the maximum amount of gas you are willing to spend for the tx, and it must be used for every type of transaction: type `0` (legacy), `1` (using access list) and `2` (EIP-1559).

You can find the complete definition of transaction for web3.js [in the repo](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0b890b70b977451836dc693614960256bcbcb6d8/packages/web3-core/types/index.d.ts#L143), and below for your convenience:

```
export interface TransactionConfig {
    from?: string | number;
    to?: string;
    value?: number | string | BN;
    gas?: number | string;
    gasPrice?: number | string | BN;
    maxPriorityFeePerGas?: number | string | BN;
    maxFeePerGas?: number | string | BN;
    data?: string;
    nonce?: number;
    chainId?: number;
    common?: Common;
    chain?: string;
    hardfork?: string;
}
```

If `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas` are set, and the `gasPrice` parameter is set, [they will be both set equal to `gasPrice`](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/ed825d2b260a249b01c3a55c822a9ca2588e961f/packages/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js#L415).

See [the test cases in the official repo](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/23e3045cdd54421ede10b3633d39e1a5576ee790/test/eth.accounts.signTransaction.js#L566) for many examples of use, like the one below. Search for `postEip1559Block` to see examples that contain `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas`.

```
it("signTransaction must compare to eth_signTransaction", function(done) {
    var provider = new FakeHttpProvider();
    var web3 = new Web3(provider);

    provider.injectResult(
        test.transaction.common.hardfork === 'london' ?
        postEip1559Block:
        preEip1559Block
    );
    provider.injectValidation(function (payload) {
        assert.equal(payload.jsonrpc, '2.0');
        assert.equal(payload.method, 'eth_getBlockByNumber');
        assert.deepEqual(payload.params, ['latest', false]);
    });
    provider.injectResult('0x5022');
    provider.injectValidation(function (payload) {
        assert.equal(payload.jsonrpc, '2.0');
        assert.equal(payload.method, 'eth_gasPrice');
        assert.deepEqual(payload.params, []);
    });

    var ethAccounts = new Accounts(web3);

    var testAccount = ethAccounts.privateKeyToAccount(test.privateKey);
    assert.equal(testAccount.address, test.address);

    testAccount.signTransaction(test.transaction).then(function (tx) {
        assert.equal(tx.messageHash, test.messageHash, "message hash failed");
        assert.equal(tx.transactionHash, test.transactionHash, "tx hash failed");
        assert.equal(tx.rawTransaction, test.rawTransaction, "rawtx failed");
        done();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(i, e)
        done(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
Genius, should have looked into the source code instead of relying on documentation

Answer (score 0):

The `sendSignedTransaction` function does not receive a `gasPrice` nor `gas`, there are the parameters -

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransactionData [, callback])
```

1. String - Signed transaction data in HEX format
2. Function - (optional) Optional callback, returns an error object as first parameter and the result as second.

So you can specify `maxFeePerGas` in [`signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) and send using `sendSignedTransaction`.

```
var Tx = require('@ethereumjs/tx').Transaction;
var privateKey = Buffer.from('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex');

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  maxFeePerGas: '0x09184e72a000',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x1C9C380'
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  value: '0x00',
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx, {'chain':'ropsten'});
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);
```

Comment: This example is for ethereumjs (https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx), OP's question was about web3.js (https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js)

Comment: It seems web3.js uses ethereumjs under the hood, so they actually use the same tx parameters ;)

Comment: Yes... this example is from web3's docs.